# Can´t populate spinner from string array in android

Tags: android, arrays, android-spinner

I have problem with populating a spinner with items from a string array. When I start the emulator nothing is shown in the spinner. The spinner is shown and it´s empty,but when I click on It nothing happens.

Here is my activity:

```
package org.example.anders.eazy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class StartActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner workoutSpinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        workoutSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerWorkout);
        adapter =ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.workout_name,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        workoutSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        workoutSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+" selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

My layout file for activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="org.example.anders.eazy.StartActivity">

    <Button
        android:id ="@+id/push_button"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:text="@string/startWorkout"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_round"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <TextView android:text="@string/workout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/push_button"
        android:id="@+id/WorkoutText"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerWorkout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/WorkoutText"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And my string array in string file looks like this:

```
<!-- Spinner options-->
<string-array name="workout_name">
    <item>Chest Workout</item>
    <item>Leg Workout</item>
    <item>Arms Workout</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: I made a mistake. In my previous activity I had just started the view of this activity not the activity itself by using intent...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
class YourActivity extends AppCompat {
    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_id);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_array));

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```